# Is there any way to assign multiple xlabels at once in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to assign multiple xlabels at once in matplotlib. 
Now I assign multiple xlabels as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(211)
ax1.set_xlabel("x label")
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_xlabel("x label")
```

I feel this way is redundant. 
Is there any way to assign multiple xlabels at once like follows?

```
(ax1,ax2).set_xlabel("x label")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a list comprehension.

```
[ax.set_xlabel("x label") for ax in [ax1,ax2]]
```

You may also already set the labels at subplot creation, which simplifies the complete code from the question to one single line:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, subplot_kw=dict(xlabel="xlabel") )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could store your `ax` objects in a list. By using the `subplots` function, this list is created for you:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

[ax.set_xlabel("x label") for ax in axes]

axes[0,0].plot(data)        # whatever you want to plot
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a normal `for`-loop, as it makes your intention clear:

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.set_xlabel("x label")
```

If you prefer a one-liner, remember the `map` function:

```
map(lambda ax : ax.set_xlabel("x label"), [ax1, ax2])
```